# CSS3 Animation infinite not working correctly in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I have a CSS3 animation, which works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but in IE11 after one full animation is weirdly jumps like there is no animation. Then it starts again. http://screencast.com/t/7KpNdnk7XX1w

```css
.main-circle {
 position: relative;
 height: 19.5rem; 
 width: 19.5rem;
 margin-left: 2rem;
 border-radius: 100%; 
 border: 1px solid black; 
}
.orbit {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 5em;
 height: 5em;
 margin-top: -2.25em;
 margin-left: -2.25em;
 border-radius: 100%; 
 border: 1px solid black;
 animation-name: orbit;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
 animation-direction: alternate-reverse; 
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 background: white;
}
@keyframes orbit {
 from { transform: rotate(355deg) translateX(-9.75em) rotate(-355deg); }
 to { transform: rotate(290deg) translateX(-9.75em) rotate(-290deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="main-circle">
 <div class="orbit"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't see any such problem on IE11 + Win 10.

Comment: See the screencast attached was made on IE11@Win10 via browserstack with this http://dabblet.com/gist/0008834232ff19226069. Also confirmed on a real IE11@Win7. The error appears AFTER the first full animation cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is super odd ! 
I can't tell you why the animation is wrong on IE11 but I found a trick to make it work well :) 
Check this codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxwXMW?editors=0100

I changed the value of `animation-direction`with `alternate` and I changed your animation a bit (`from` --> `0%, 0.01%` and `to` -> `100%`)

Tell me if it's fixed on your computer :)

Comment: Awesome. This fixes the issue! This is clearly a bug in IE11, which they seem to have fixed in Edge. :)

Comment: Gosh, I totally forgot about this 0.01 strange fix. My case the animation was being set to opacity: 0; changing it to 0.01 instead of 0 fixes IE11 =/